SOAP UI throwing this error while mocking a response of a service

./mockservicerunner.sh: line 58: 30285 Killed                  java
$JAVA_OPTS -cp $SOAPUI_CLASSPATH
com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUIMockServiceRunner "$@"

================================
=
= SOAPUI_HOME = /home/eksimssit/SoapUI-5.4.0
=
================================
================================
=
= SOAPUI_HOME = /home/eksimssit/SoapUI-5.4.0
=
================================
2024-04-09 13:23:49,839 [main] WARN  com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI - Could not find jfxrt.jar. Internal browser will be disabled.
SoapUI 5.4.0 MockService Runner
2024-04-09 13:23:49,844 [main] WARN  com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI - Could not find jfxrt.jar. Internal browser will be disabled.
SoapUI 5.4.0 MockService Runner
13:23:50,017 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/home/eksimssit/soapui-settings.xml]
13:23:50,018 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/home/eksimssit/soapui-settings.xml]
13:23:50,809 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 3 ms
13:23:50,809 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
13:23:50,817 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 1 ms
13:23:50,818 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
13:23:51,469 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/home/eksimssit/SoapUI-5.4.0/authenticate-soapui-project.xml]
13:23:51,475 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] Running MockService [authenticate] in project [authenticate]
13:23:51,475 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] Press any key to terminate
13:23:51,568 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/home/eksimssit/SoapUI-5.4.0/Aunthentication-soapui-project.xml]
13:23:51,574 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] Running MockService [Aunthentication] in project [Aunthentication]
13:23:51,574 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] Press any key to terminate
13:23:51,574 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] Started 0 runners
Press any key to terminate...
13:23:51,584 INFO  [JettyMockEngine] Started mockService [authenticate] on port [8090] at path [/]
13:23:51,585 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] MockService started on port 8090 at path [/]
13:23:51,585 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] Started 1 runner
Press any key to terminate...
13:23:52,574 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] time taken: 1000ms
13:24:42,416 INFO  [SoapUIMockServiceRunner] Handled request 1 - [missing mockResponse] in [0ms] at [2024-04-09 13:24:42.415]
./mockservicerunner.sh: line 58: 18574 Killed                  java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $SOAPUI_CLASSPATH com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUIMockServiceRunner "$@"

I want to read the response from the .xml file which i stubbed but its throwing error

Can you show the script used to achieve the same?
